# folder making from files

Tags: python, linux, shell

This is how my files look like..

```
   a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-a.png
   a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-b.png
```

I've like thousands of files like this. 
Can we make folders for each set of files like `a-b`
Can I grep it? how can I do it?

```
import glob, itertools, os
import re
foo = glob.glob('*.png')

for a in range(len(foo)):
        print foo[a]
        match=re.match("[a-zA-Z0-9] - [a-zA-Z0-9] - *",foo[a])
        print "match",match
```

So, what's the error there?

Comment: Yes you can. Do the appropriate string operations and invoke the `mkdir` syscall as wrapped by Python.

Comment: Can you point me to an example or something ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=mkdir#os.mkdir & http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#string

Comment: try the code suggested and update your question with your efforts if/when you are stuck and we'd be glad to assist you further

Comment: @Fredrik: can you have a look at the core there.

Comment: Terrible update, but see my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of all files with `glob.glob('*.png')`.

You can then parse every filename using regex (`import re`).

Make dirs using `os.mkdir(path)`.

Move files using `os.rename(src, dst)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for what you want to do:

```
import os

path="./"
my_list = os.listdir(path)   #lists all the files & folders in the path ./ (i.e. the current path)

for my_file in my_list:
    if ".png" in my_file:
        its_folder="something..."
        if not os.path.isdir(its_folder):
            os.mkdir(its_folder)     #creates a new folder
        os.rename('./'+my_file, './'+its_folder+'/'+my_file)    #moves a file to the folder some_folder.
```

You have to specify the name for each folder you want to create, and to move files into, (instead of "something...") eg:

```
its_folder=my_file[0:3];    #if my_file is "a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-a.png" the corresponding folder would have its first 3 characters: "a-b".
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you stared, adapt to your own needs:

Lets create some files:

```
$ touch a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-{a..f}.png


$ ls
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-a.png  a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-c.png  a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-e.png  f.py
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-b.png  a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-d.png  a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-f.png
```

Some python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob, os

files = glob.glob('*.png')

for f in files:
    # get the character before the dot
    d = f.split('-')[-1][0]
    #create directory
    try:
        os.mkdir(d)
    except OSError as e:
        print 'unable to creade dir', d, e
    #move file
    try:
        os.rename(f, os.path.join(d, f))
    except OSError as e:
        print 'unable to move file', f, e
```

Lets run it

```
$ ./f.py

$ ls -R
.:
a  b  c  d  e  f  f.py

./a:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-a.png

./b:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-b.png

./c:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-c.png

./d:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-d.png

./e:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-e.png

./f:
a-b-2013-02-12-16-38-54-f.png
```